# Sort highscores in file python programming

Tags: python

I have a game that I am programming, the highest score will be saved down onto a file in where it shall be sorted after the best score etc. I have coded a class and a way to save down the score, but cannot figure out how to sort them after eachother like:
Ex:

```
16

9

3
```

## The final Score process!

```
# Display the final score.
drawBoard(mainBoard)
scores = getScoreOfBoard(mainBoard)
```

Comment: so you want to print it out like 8 5 3 1 instead of `[1,3,5,8]` ? or what is actually your problem?

Comment: No I want to sort it in my file, so when I open highscores.txt I want list of numbers descending

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
def save_highscore(self, highscore):
    highscores = set(self.get_highscores(False))  
    if highscore in highscores:  
        return  
    highscores.add(highscore)  
    with open(self.HIGHSCORE_FILE, "w") as f: 
       f.write(" ".join(str(score) for score in highscores))
```

to

```
def save_highscore(self, highscore):
    highscores = set(self.get_highscores(False))  
    if highscore in highscores:  
        return  
    highscores.add(highscore)  
    with open(self.HIGHSCORE_FILE, "w") as f: 
       f.write("\n".join(str(score) for score in sorted(highscores, reverse=True)))
```

Comment: Okey, in the file I then get ex: `2 4 5 10 12`. How do I sort it like:

Comment: 12 enter 10 enter 5 enter 4 enter 2

Comment: you have to also change `highscores = set(self.get_highscores(False))` to `highscores = set(self.get_highscores(True))`

Comment: yeah, ty but is there a way to change it to a highscore list as mentioned above?

Comment: like each number on a separate line?

Comment: ` f.write("\n".join(str(score) for score in sorted(highscores, reverse=True)))` = you must join with new line `\n`

Answer (score 0):

You need reverse=True to be passed into the sorted function, like so:

```
return sorted(scores, reverse=True)
```

A simple fix would be to sort the high scores before you write them to the file:

```
with open(self.HIGHSCORE_FILE, "w") as f:
    f.write("\n".join(str(score) for score in sorted(highscores, reverse=True)))
```

However this completely rewrites and sorts the file every time you add a high score. A better way to do this would be to simply insert each score into the correct line in the file.

Comment: Okey, in the file I then get ex: 2 4 5 10 12. How do I sort it like: a highscore with the 12 as highest and then descending numbers underneth

Comment: Ah I see, let me edit my answer. I added a quick solution.

Comment: Thank you! :)))))